# Faucet handle removal

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, water, faucet

I’m trying to replace my bathroom faucet (I turned off the water supply lines) and cannot get the base of the handles off.

Here are photos of the top and bottom:

[image: top]
[image: bottom]

Anything I should try?

Comment: the silver dome in the top picture should unscrew or just lift off ... slide a knife blade under it

Comment: while I agree with jstola on the top piece, you said you want to take it off, to do that you need to remove the "T" and then the nut above it that is rusted as you have pictured.

Comment: Mine was on so tight I ended up damaging it but it did come off. I believe I used vice grips, one for the bottom nut and one on the top part...I may have even had to hammer the vice grip once it was firmly attached.

Answer (score 1):

This is a NUT: [image]

Channel locks or a slip lock wrench will work. Remove the metal piece on the threaded pipe first.

For the top, I agreee with @jstola but it looks kinda like someone may have filled the bell housing with caulk (the white goo out the top doesn't belog there).
Once in a while, these housings have a small recessed hole with an allen nut inside; yours does not look like one of these, but if you see a small hole in it that looks useless, it probably is.
Also, sometimes these fixtures are also threaded on (and I believe sometimes they are a reverse thread), yours could very well be one of these. If it is caulked inside, you might need to (sensibly) apply some heat to get it to break/melt free.  Definitiely try the putty knife idea first, clean off all excess plumbers putty or caulk, and remove anything plastic. Dont cook the countertop.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to take the chrome cover off of the top.  My guess is that you will find a nut under there that you can remove with a wrench.  Since you are replacing the item you don't have to be too careful with it. I'd just grab it with a channel-loc and try to unscrew it. Last resort would be to cut the cover off. I'd use a Dremel but a hacksaw would do.

Comment: The chrome cover could be just to access the mechanism so you can take it apart to replace the washer. Dripping fawcets are often due to the washer needing replacement rather than the whole unit. @noybman is correct that the nut under the counter top needs removing to replace the whole unit.

Answer (score -1):

Spray the rusted nut with WD40 or another type penetrating oil, helps a lot when fighting rust.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming.